# Dynamically Reporting or Adding fields on Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a very poorly designed back end system which I cannot change.  To keep it simple for the purpose of this question, the data looks like this:

> VendorNumber,
>   ItemNumber,
>   PONumber,
>   DocumentNumber,
>   PiecesToDistribute1,
>   PiecesToDistribute2,
>   PiecesToDistribute3,
>   PiecesToDistribute4,
>   .....
>   PiecesToDistribute300

The number at the end of PiecesToDistribute## refers to store numbers.

I need to show in the report pieces to distribute to each location where the field is not 0 but at 300 potential columns wide I'm struggling for ideas to make this work.  I attempted to do a sub report with a 300 line union as a command table (ok, I tried it only with 5 lines first) putting paramaters in the SQL but the report wizard "link" screen does not seem to give me parameters from SQL as options to link to.

I do have a table with my store numbers (which may change over time).

Is there any way to dynamically select the field (even by iteration) based off a link back to the table with store numbers?  e.g. dynamically build the name of the field  (similar to Excel's indirect() function).

I basically want my output to be:

```
ItemNum     Description Item                         Cost      Retail
ABCD1234    Some Widget My Company Has Here          25.00      35.00
           Loc 1:   4             Loc 7:  3
           Loc 2:   3             Loc 9:  8
           Loc 3:   2             Loc 16:  5
           Loc 4:   2             Loc 98:  8
```

If there was a separate table with the distribution lines this would be a non issue, but as it is now, I'm a little stumped.   Immediate solution I can hard code this for only active stores, but that is not maintainable long term.

What am I missing or any good ideas?
(modifying the back end system is not an option;  I doubt that the vendor of the purchasing system will change their schema any time soon, it has probably been this way for 20 years)

Comment: did you find any solution for this??? im in the same position right now and im not sure what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the data before to pass it to the report.